# Remove prefix from homepage title

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, custom, home

My homepage is showing my domain (www.domain.com) as prefix before title. I didn't put the prefix in cms homepage but on google it is showing as (www.domain.com then title). How can i remove that prefix from homepage title? can anyone help?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you check Configuration -> Design -> HTML Head -> Default Title

Be aware of Store Scope.

Comment: yes i have checked that also, its not there in default title